# how to read server environment variables at run-time in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, environment-variables, runtime

In node we can do this: `console.log(process.env)` to get a full list of ENV variables available on a server.

Please how can we do same in Vue.js

The Vue-CLI documentation for environment variables is not clear on runtime variables.

**Example**:

Say I am building an app which I hand off to a 3rd party.
They need to add `SOME_RUNTIME_KEY` to their server environment and set it to some value which i can't know at build-time, maybe the value is peculiar to their environment.

How do i configure such a dynamic runtime-variable in vue.js?

Comment: did you check this https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#example-staging-mode ?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim that will not help. For example i am building an app which i hand off to a 3rd party,  they need to add SOME_RUNTIME_KEY to their server environment and set it to some value which i cant know @ build time, maybe the value is particular to their environment.

How do i configure such dynamic runtime-variables in vuejs?